# How to use OpenGL 3/4

Tags: opengl

in my new project I wanna use OpenGL version 3/4, but I don't find any references about which libraries or header files I have to use.

I look on the [offical OpenGL homepage](http://www.opengl.org/), but there I can't find any libraries.
Where I have to download the new versions of OpenGL?

Comment: It's the same library and headers, you just have to create the context differently.

Comment: "*I look on the offical OpenGL homepage,*" You didn't look very hard. It's right there on [the Wiki's Getting Started page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started).

Answer (score 0):

As Pubby said in his comment, you still use the OpenGL library. But you should probably use the library headers that can be found at http://www.opengl.org/registry/, and you will have to create the context differently. For example, with [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/), I do something like this:

```
GLenum init_window(int w, int h)
{
        int major, minor, rev;
        GLenum glewResult;

        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: could not init GLFW\n");
                return GL_FALSE;
        }
        glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
        printf("GLFW %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, rev);

        glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        if (!glfwOpenWindow(w, h, 0,0,0,0, 24,0, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open window\n");
                glfwTerminate();
                return GL_FALSE;
        }

        glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
        fprintf(stderr, "Context: OpenGL %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, rev);

        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glewResult = glewInit();
        if (glewResult != GLEW_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: could not init GLEW\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glewResult));
                glfwTerminate();
                return GL_FALSE;
        }
        return GL_TRUE;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: No, how you create the context depends on the library you use. GLFW is a window and input library that gives you 1 window and attaches a context to it. My code snippet is merely an example of how I do it using GLFW in particular.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is library implemented by GPU vendors. If you have a decent GPU then you have probably OpenGL 3 or 4.
On Windows by default there is only OpenGL 1.1, but vendors implement "full" OpenGL using extensions. In general you should use some helper library to get those extensions (or write your own code :))

If you want to use "modern" OpenGL. Just try to use Core functionality from OpenGL 3.3 at least.

great source of info: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page

books: http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/